# Polars: expanding window at fixed points

Tags: python, python-polars

I have a `Polars` dataframe with 3 columns - group, date, value. The goal is to calculate `cumsum(value)` for each expanding window ends at the first time point at each year for each `group`.

For example, for the following sample dataframe:

```
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "date": [
            "2020-03-01",
            "2020-05-01",
            "2020-11-01",
            "2021-01-01",
            "2021-02-03",
            "2021-06-08",
            "2022-01-05",
            "2020-07-01",
            "2020-09-01",
            "2022-01-05",
            "2023-02-04",
        ],
        "group": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        "value": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4],
    },
).with_columns(pl.col("date").str.strptime(pl.Date))
```

The result I am looking for is:

```
┌────────────┬───────┬───────┐
│ date       ┆ group ┆ value │
│ ---        ┆ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ date       ┆ i64   ┆ i64   │
╞════════════╪═══════╪═══════╡
│ 2020-03-01 ┆ 1     ┆ 1     │
│ 2021-01-01 ┆ 1     ┆ 10    │
│ 2022-01-05 ┆ 1     ┆ 28    │
│ 2020-07-01 ┆ 2     ┆ 1     │
│ 2022-01-05 ┆ 2     ┆ 6     │
│ 2023-02-04 ┆ 2     ┆ 10    │
└────────────┴───────┴───────┘
```

Basically, at the first date of each year, calculate the cumulative sum of `value` from beginning up to (including) this particular date, for each group respectively.

I tried `group_by_dynamic` and `rolling`, but still unable to find a concise and clear way to solve this problem.

Any idea is welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A "naive" approach could be to calculate the full `cum_sum` and then keep the first yearly row of each group.

```py
df.with_columns(
   cum_sum = pl.col("value").cum_sum().over("group")
).filter(
   pl.col("date").dt.year().is_first_distinct().over("group")
)
```

```py
shape: (6, 4)
┌────────────┬───────┬───────┬─────────┐
│ date       ┆ group ┆ value ┆ cum_sum │
│ ---        ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---     │
│ date       ┆ i64   ┆ i64   ┆ i64     │
╞════════════╪═══════╪═══════╪═════════╡
│ 2020-03-01 ┆ 1     ┆ 1     ┆ 1       │
│ 2021-01-01 ┆ 1     ┆ 4     ┆ 10      │
│ 2022-01-05 ┆ 1     ┆ 7     ┆ 28      │
│ 2020-07-01 ┆ 2     ┆ 1     ┆ 1       │
│ 2022-01-05 ┆ 2     ┆ 3     ┆ 6       │
│ 2023-02-04 ┆ 2     ┆ 4     ┆ 10      │
└────────────┴───────┴───────┴─────────┘
```

A more "direct" (efficient) approach could be to take the yearly sum first, then calculate the `cum_sum`:

```py
(df.group_by(
      "group", 
      pl.col("date").dt.year().alias("year"),
      maintain_order=True
   )
   .agg(
      pl.col("date").first(),
      pl.col("value").first(), 
      pl.col("value").sum().alias("sum"),
   )
   .with_columns(
      pl.when(pl.col("group").is_first_distinct())
        .then(pl.col("value"))
        .otherwise(
           pl.col("value") + pl.col("sum").cum_sum().shift().over("group")
        )
        .alias("cum_sum")
   )
)
```

```py
shape: (6, 6)
┌───────┬──────┬────────────┬───────┬─────┬─────────┐
│ group ┆ year ┆ date       ┆ value ┆ sum ┆ cum_sum │
│ ---   ┆ ---  ┆ ---        ┆ ---   ┆ --- ┆ ---     │
│ i64   ┆ i32  ┆ date       ┆ i64   ┆ i64 ┆ i64     │
╞═══════╪══════╪════════════╪═══════╪═════╪═════════╡
│ 1     ┆ 2020 ┆ 2020-03-01 ┆ 1     ┆ 6   ┆ 1       │
│ 1     ┆ 2021 ┆ 2021-01-01 ┆ 4     ┆ 15  ┆ 10      │
│ 1     ┆ 2022 ┆ 2022-01-05 ┆ 7     ┆ 7   ┆ 28      │
│ 2     ┆ 2020 ┆ 2020-07-01 ┆ 1     ┆ 3   ┆ 1       │
│ 2     ┆ 2022 ┆ 2022-01-05 ┆ 3     ┆ 3   ┆ 6       │
│ 2     ┆ 2023 ┆ 2023-02-04 ┆ 4     ┆ 4   ┆ 10      │
└───────┴──────┴────────────┴───────┴─────┴─────────┘
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to achieve the goal in a more direct way? If I have daily data for a lot of years, the proposed solution will waste ~360x calculations.

Comment: @lebesgue You can calculate the yearly sum first and then generate the cum_sum. It's a bit more involved but should be more efficient. I've added an example if you'd like to benchmark it.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably going to need to break this one out into 2 steps:

1. Calculate the cumulative value and year of each entry
2. determine the first date in each year (into a separate dataframe)
3. join the two results into a composite result, on the group and year.

Here's one way of doing that:

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "date": [
            "2020-03-01",
            "2020-05-01",
            "2020-11-01",
            "2021-01-01",
            "2021-02-03",
            "2021-06-08",
            "2022-01-05",
            "2020-07-01",
            "2020-09-01",
            "2022-01-05",
            "2023-02-04",
        ],
        "group": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        "value": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4],
    },
).with_columns([
    pl.col("date").str.strptime(pl.Date)
])

# Calculate the cumulative sum of "value" for each group
df = df.with_columns(
    [
        pl.col("value").cum_sum().over("group").alias("cumulative_value"),
        pl.col("date").dt.year().alias("year")
    ]
)


# Identify the first date of each year for each group
first_date_each_year = df.group_by(["group", "year"]).agg(pl.col("date").min().alias("first_date_of_year"))

print(first_date_each_year)

# Join to get the cumulative sum at the first date of each year for each group
result_df = df.join(
    first_date_each_year,
    on=["group", "year"],
    how="inner"
).filter(pl.col("date") == pl.col("first_date_of_year"))

# Select and rename columns as needed
result_df = result_df.select(
    [
        pl.col("first_date_of_year").alias("date"),
        "group",
        pl.col("cumulative_value").alias("value")
    ]
)

print(result_df)
```

Which yields the desired result:

```
┌────────────┬───────┬───────┐
│ date       ┆ group ┆ value │
│ ---        ┆ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ date       ┆ i64   ┆ i64   │
╞════════════╪═══════╪═══════╡
│ 2020-03-01 ┆ 1     ┆ 1     │
│ 2021-01-01 ┆ 1     ┆ 10    │
│ 2022-01-05 ┆ 1     ┆ 28    │
│ 2020-07-01 ┆ 2     ┆ 1     │
│ 2022-01-05 ┆ 2     ┆ 6     │
│ 2023-02-04 ┆ 2     ┆ 10    │
└────────────┴───────┴───────┘
```